# QLabel doesn't display pixmap

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to display a `QPixmap` in `QLabel`, but I get the label empty.

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Test(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("test.png")

        lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        self.move(300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.show()        

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Test()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I start the application, I only get an empty window :

[image: empty window]

I use a Linux distribution (Manjaro). I tested with Ubuntu, but I had the same problem.

I don't understand what is wrong, since I succeed to display other `QPixmaps` in `QGraphicsScene` and `QIcon` in `QPushButton`.

How can I display a `QPixmap` in my label ?

**EDIT:**

Here is an other version with a layout, but which don't solve the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Test(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("test.png")

        lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        layout.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.move(300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')
        self.show()        

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Test()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Check that pixmap loads ok.

Comment: @hyde Yes, I can get its size for example. If I load the image through the `load()` method, it returns `True` and I get the same result.

Comment: Try using layout or resizing the label yourself.

Comment: The layout doesn't change anything.

Comment: Works for me (both versions) - the code is generally correct. Are you sure that you are launching the script from the same directory where the `.png` file is located? How do you launch the script (from the command line / from an IDE)?

Comment: Yes, I launched the script in the same directory. But I realized that if I use an absolute path, it works. So it must be a path problem. Tank you for your help.

Comment: @arthropode For your reference, here is the exact code I used for testing: https://github.com/afester/StackOverflow/tree/master/Python/PyQtPixmap - the python scripts are an exact copy of your code from the question, when I launch the scripts on the command line like `./v1.py` from within the `PyQtPixmap` directory, the image is shown

Comment: Try replacing `QtGui.QPixmap("test.png")` with `QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/test.png")` - of course, create the images directory first and move the test.png there.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble not is the path
The trouble is when execute the program from VSC 
If you execute the program in CMD or TERMINAL the program RUN and Show the Image !
Tested !